# Can't display images by looping through folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have images included with my ASP.NET project under the `img` folder. I'm trying to automate the process of displaying the images without having to manually add each one.

I tried:

```
@foreach (var image in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/img/portfolio/engagement")))
{
    <li class="span3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="@image"/></a></li>
}
```

This outputs:

```
    <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="C:\Users\Cody\Documents\CMBS\CodySolution\CodySolution\img\portfolio\engagement\IMG_0093.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li class="span3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="C:\Users\Cody\Documents\CMBS\CodySolution\CodySolution\img\portfolio\engagement\IMG_0130.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li class="span3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="C:\Users\Cody\Documents\CMBS\CodySolution\CodySolution\img\portfolio\engagement\IMG_0144.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li class="span3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="C:\Users\Cody\Documents\CMBS\CodySolution\CodySolution\img\portfolio\engagement\IMG_9931.jpg"/></a></li>
    </ul>
```

This doesn't work. The images do not show and when I try to follow the direct link, it tells me `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).`

What is the proper way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `Server.MapPath` gives you the physical directory of where your web app resides on your server.

Try using `Url.Content()` instead. This will give you an http path like `http://www.yoursite.com/Content/file.jpg`

For example:

```
var path = "~/Content/Whatever/";
var listOfFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(path))
    .Select(p => path + Path.GetFileName(p));

@foreach (var item in listOfFileNames)
{
    <img src="@Url.Content(item)" />
}
```

Comment: While still using the `Server.MapPath`? This doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You don't need the full server path, just the file names. I'll update my answer.